# In Q, how do I get the rows for the last X minutes from a Kdb table?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with price info. And building a front-end functionality that allows the user to see all prices from the last X minutes, where user specifies X.

How do I query this in q?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your table is named `trades`, and the `trades` table has a time column you can use the following function to achieve the desired output:

```
q){select from trades where time >= .z.n-`minute$x}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say your table is called `table`. You could create a function `f` which takes one argument `x`:the number of minutes previously you want to select from.

```
q)f:{select price from table where time within (.z.p-`minute$x;.z.p)}
```

Then, for example to get price info from the last 15 minutes you would do:

```
q)f[15]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked too